# LLVM get the condition of invoke instruction

Tags: llvm

In the official documentation, it says `invoke` instruction goes to normal when the callee function returns with the `ret` instruction. Otherwise, it goes to the exception label.

I think there is a signal to tell that when it satisfies the normal label condition or not. If I am writing a pass using LLVM IR, how can I the signal (if exists) or change `invoke` to `call` instruction with exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it is not possible to tell if the function wouldn't throw an exception without running it. So, there is no such condition you can check on statically.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Well, I also searched that `invoke` and `call` can both handle the exception. How can I convert `invoke` to `call` with the exception handling strategy?

Comment: You can use `ReplaceInstWithInst()` from http://llvm.org/doxygen/BasicBlockUtils_8h.html